# On the MacBook Pro, send file links via iMessage?

Tags: macos, messages, nas, links

I have two Macbook Pros in my office.  I would like to send a link to a file (specifying its path) to another user, using that other MacBook Pro. We have a commonly mounted network drive. So I would just like to send the link to the file I'm asking her to reference.  I can see that the 'add link' feature lets people attach URLs.  But what about these semi-private files on the local network?

Comment: Can’t you just copy-paste the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you can drag a file into a terminal window to get the full path and that would be something you could paste into an iMessage window.

If you want it to be a true link to the file, prepend the path with file://

- file:///Volumes/NAS/path/to/file

Comment: Does about 90% of what I hoped it would.  When I have the full path to the file (e.g. a .doc), iMessage will only invoke the Finder to display the folder that holds the file.  iMessage isn't smart enough to get MS Word application started and actually show the file.